# How to visualize variations between columns through plot pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, ggplot2

I have a data frame shown in the figure; some mismatches exist in the rows. I want to plot the first column versus all the other columns to depict the variation. Can anyone tell me how I can do that.?

[image: DataFrame]

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [2D heatmap](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html) to show the differences:

For example, if you had a dataframe like this:

#### Dataframe:

```
   U  V  W  X  Y  Z
0  M  M  M  M  M  M
1  K  K  R  K  K  K
2  A  A  A  A  B  A
3  I  I  I  I  I  I
4  L  L  L  L  L  L
```

You could use the following code to identify the differences to that in column `U`:

#### Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"U":['M','K','A','I','L'], "V":['M','K','A','I','L'], "W":['M','R','A','I','L'], "X":['M','K','A','I','L'], "Y":['M','K','B','I','L'], "Z":['M','K','A','I','L']})


# Create a new dataframe with the differences between the values in each column and the values in the first column
diff_df = df.apply(lambda x: x != df['U'])

# Convert the dataframe to a numpy array
diff_arr = diff_df.values


cmap = plt.cm.RdYlGn_r
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(diff_arr, cmap=cmap)
cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('Differences', rotation=-90, va="bottom")


ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(df.columns)))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(df)))
ax.set_xticklabels(df.columns)
ax.set_yticklabels(df.index)

for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in range(len(df.columns)):
        text = ax.text(j, i, df.iloc[i, j], ha="center", va="center", color="w")

ax.set_title("Differences")
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

#### Output:

[image: Output]